# async/await в парсере

Tags: c#

Нужно спарсить информацию о пользователях сайта.

Есть класс, который представляет пользователя:

```
class User
{
    public int Id {get; private set;}
    public string Name {get; private set;}  
}
```

И есть асинхронный метод, который получает информацию о пользователе по ссылке и возвращает экземпляр `User`:

```
public async Task<User> GetUserByUrl(string url)
{
    string source = await HttpGetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

    int id = Regex.Match(source, @"...").Value;
    string name = Regex.Match(source, @"...").Value;

    User user = new User();
    user.Id = id;
    user.Name = name;

    return user;
}
```

Главный метод перебирает коллекцию ссылок на пользователей и вызывает метод `GetUserByUrl`:

```
public async Task<List<User>> Parser(List<string> links)
{
    var users = new List<User>();

    for(int i = 0; i<links.Count; i++)
    {
        var user = await GetUserById(links.ElementAt(i)).ConfigureAwait(false); 
        users.Add(user);
    }

    return users;
}
```

Все бы ничего, но скорость работы очень медленная. Похоже, что все работает синхронно.

Раньше у меня было сделано так, что метод `GetUserByUrl` находился в классе `User` и ничего не возвращал, а изменял его же свойства.

Главный метод выглядел так и парсилось все гораздо быстрее:

```
public async Task<List<User>> Parser(List<string> links)
{
    var _tasks = new List<Task>();

    for(int i = 0; i<links.Count; i++)
    {
        var user = new User();
        _tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => user.GetUserByUrl(links.ElementAt(i))).ContinueWith(task => users.Add(user)));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
    return users;
}
```

Почему в первом случае метод отрабатывает медленно (синхронно?) и как его заставить работать быстрее?

Comment: _Похоже, что все работает синхронно._ - не синхронно, а последовательно

Comment: Если у сайта есть API, воспользуйтесь им. Если нет — то и не нужно ничего делать.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Асинхронность и многопоточноть - это две совершенно разные вещи.

Асинхронность - это возможность не блокировать выполнение на время сетевых или дисковых вызовов. Она не ускоряет выполнение сама по себе.

`async`/`await` - это инструмент асинхронности. Он просто позволяет вам делать *что-то еще* во время ожидания ответа от сервера.

Ваш цикл работает (возможно) асинхронно, но однопоточно - он просто не ставит на выполнение вытягивание следующего пользователя до тех пор, пока не получит данные предыдущего. Проблема в том, что вы явно ждете данных пользователя.

```
var user = await GetUserById(links.ElementAt(i)).ConfigureAwait(false); 
users.Add(user);
```

Очевидно, что выполнение просто не дойдет до следующей итерации цикла до тех пор, пока вы не вытяните и не распарсите данные текущей итерации.

Мнопоточность - это использование нескольких одновременных потоков выполнения для обработки данных.

`Task.Run` - это запуск делегата на выполнение в отдельном потоке из пула. Весь код, который вы в него забрасываете, выполняется в отдельных потоках. И видно, что вы сначала забрасываете вытягивание всех пользователей, а уже потом начинаете ждать результата. Естественно, это работает быстрее. Если вам не принципиально использовать `async`/`await` - оставьте этот вариант.

Только исправьте в нем проблему с доступом к списку `users` из разных потоков - `List<T>` не потокобезопасен - иначе вы будете терять данные. Стоит ждать таски как есть, а в список складывать их `.Result`-ы уже после завершения.

Вы можете получить тот же или близкий результат на `async`/`await`, если не будете ждать выполнения, а точно так же сложите результаты вызовов `GetUserById` в список тасков, и в конце точно так же сделаете `await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);`

Comment: Мне интересны оба варианта реализации и через `Task.Run`, и через `async/await`.

Если я складываю задачи в коллекцию так:
`_tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => api.GetUserByUrl(links.ElementAt(i))).ContinueWith(task => users.Add(task.Result)));` и затем 
ожидаю их выполнения через `await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);`, то несколько пользователей парсится нормально и затем возникает исключение `System.AggregateException` на моменте добавления в коллекцию. Пишет, что произошла одна или несколько ошибок и при этом, `task.Result` не вычислен.

Comment: Если делать без `Task.Run` и в конце `await Task.WhenAll(_tasks)`, то происходит тоже самое. 
Это как раз то, о чем вы говорили касаемо доступа к списку `users`? 

Подскажите, как я могу сначала положить таски на выполнение, а затем уже добавлять результаты выполнения в коллекцию?

Comment: @maxwell просто складывайте в коллекцию таски без вызова `.ContinueWith(task => users.Add(task.Result))`. После ожидания тасков делайте `_tasks.Select(t => t.Result).ToList();`

Comment: @maxwell посмотрите решение в ответе от Monk :)

Answer (score 4):

Итак, что у нас есть асинхронного, но почему то не быстрого:

```
public async Task<List<User>> Parser(List<string> links)
{
    var users = new List<User>();

    for(int i = 0; i<links.Count; i++)
    {
        var user = await GetUserById(links.ElementAt(i)).ConfigureAwait(false); 
        users.Add(user);
    }

    return users;
}
```

Как это легко заставить шевелиться пошустрее:

```
public async Task<List<User>> Parser(List<string> links)
{
  var users = links.Select(GetUserById).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(users);
  return users.Select(u => u.Result).ToList();
}
```

Главное - не ждать конкретный элемент, чтобы его засунуть в результирующий список, а дождаться сразу всех и вернуть их.

Стоит понимать, что следующая после `await` строчка кода, работающая с результатом задачи будет этой самой задачи дожидаться. Поэтому в цикле их лучше не использовать, а строить коллекцию таких задачек и ждать их через `WhenAll` \ `WhenAny`.

Comment: Подскажите, я правильно понимаю, что уже на этом этапе `var users = links.Select(GetUserById).ToList();`  добавленная задача начинает выполняться, а с помощью `Task.WhenAll` мы ожидаем, чтобы все задачи наверняка выполнились?

Comment: @maxwell не задумывался никогда над этим. В этой строчке явно собирается список задач, а кто и когда их запустит - решает тредпул вроде как.

Answer (score 0):

В первом методе вы вызываете задачу и тут же ожидаете результата ее выполнения, и так для каждого элемента в List.

```
var user = await GetUserById(links.ElementAt(i)).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Во втором методе вы cначала запускаете **все** задачи (для каждого элемента)

```
_tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => user.GetUserByUrl(links.ElementAt(i))).ContinueWith(task => users.Add(user)));
```

и только потом ожидаете их.

```
await Task.WhenAll(_tasks);
```

Поэтому второй вариант и может быть быстрее.

Comment: Хорошо. Но если я делаю так `var user = GetUserById(links.ElementAt(i)).ConfigureAwait(false);` и затем кладу объект в коллекцию `AddToProducts(product.Result);`, то скорость остается прежней. Мне нужно отказаться от этого варианта и делать все через `Task.Run`?

Comment: @maxwell Вызов Task.Result блокирует вызывающий поток и ожидает результата т.е. все выполняется также последовательно. Вызов Task.Run наплодит столько потоков, сколько элементов в коллекции. Я бы написал что-то типо  _tasks.Add(user.GetUserByUrl(links.ElementAt(i))).ContinueWith(task => users.Add(user)); Тогда не будет использовано неимоверное количество потоков из ThreadPool.

Comment: Если `Task.Run` плодит потоки, то как затем запустить на выполнение список задач при этом ограничив количество потоков?

Comment: @maxwell ключевое различие решений - не в `Task.Run`, а в строке `await Task.WhenAll`.